# Script to use Windows Authentication to fetch data from SQL table and to write it back in .txt file

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, windows-authentication

I am looking for some Power Shell script to fetch data from a SQL Server table using windows authentication and write it back to .txt file.

I am very new to Power Shell thing and never worked on this before. So if somebody could guide me in this effort.

Comment: What did you try so far? What went well, what went wrong?

Comment: There is this amazing service called Google. What have you found so far with it? Which search keywords you've used?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you guys. I am able to google and make a script working according to requirement.

Here it is

```
#Script parameters 
param( 
        #Name of MS SQL Server instance 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
               HelpMessage="Specify the SQL Server name where will be run a T-SQL code",Position=0)] 
        [String] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        $server = $(throw "sqlserver parameter is required."), 

        #Database name for execution context 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
               HelpMessage="Specify the context database name",Position=1)] 
        [String] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        $dbname = $(throw "dbname parameter is required.")

    )

$connectionString = “Server=$server;Database=$dbname;Integrated Security=True;”

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()

$query = “SELECT type,name FROM sys.tables"

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)


$table | Out-File D:\test\swedes$dbname.txt


$connection.Close()
```

Now I am looking for a way to run this script on a remote SQL Server and save the results.
I am googling about this but still if someone knows a way to run this script using SSIS please help.

Comment: If you are planning to use SSIS, there isn't any need for custom Powershell. Just create a data flow and output to a file.